# Application process is getting closed when activity is initiated

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-location

I am trying to run the application in the background but when the application starts immediately the application is closed (no error is coming).I have used asynk task in the main activity.

code:

```
package com.android.trace;

public class LocationStat extends Activity {

double logi;
double lat;
long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Millisecon
Location loc;
LocationManager manager;
TextView t;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new MyLocationAsyncTask().execute();

}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    new MyLocationAsyncTask().execute();

}

private class MyLocationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Location, Void> implements LocationListener {

    //private Location l;
    //location management variables to track and maintain user location
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationAsyncTask());


        return onLocationChanged();
    }

    //this method is never executed i dont know why...?
    public Void onLocationChanged() {
        if (manager != null) {
            LocationStat l = new LocationStat();
            loc = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            lat = loc.getLatitude();
            logi = loc.getLongitude();
            t.setText(" Your Location :\nlongitude:" + logi + "\nlatitude: " + lat);                 //Log.d("Your Location", ""+latLocation);
            l.webcall(logi, lat);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        onLocationChanged();


    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

public void webcall(double logi, double lat) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    //the year data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("logitude", Double.toString(logi)));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(lat)));

    //http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/location.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(LocationStat.this, "Error in http connection " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();




        Toast.makeText(LocationStat.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(LocationStat.this, "Error converting result " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

the code for service to intiate the activity 
code:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;


import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

String tag="TestService";
@Override
public void onCreate() {

   Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, LocationStat.class);
       dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

      this.startActivity(dialogIntent);
    }

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
   super.onStart(intent, startId);  


 }

    @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   return START_STICKY;
  }
  @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

   @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   return null;
   }
}
```

The broadcast receiver used for initiating the service at the start up is

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    startServiceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startService(startServiceIntent);

  }
}
```

the manifest permissions for activity,service and broadcast receiver is as follows

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.android.trace.MyService"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.android.trace.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
            <intent-filter>  
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
             </intent-filter>  
        </receiver> 


    <activity
        android:name=".LocationStat"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_location_stat" >
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Anybody experiencing the same?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Service` instead of `Activity` to do background long run jobs

Answer (score 0):

You can only use setText and other operations on the GUI from the main GUI thread. You are trying to do this from the background thread you have started.

You must implement the AsyncTask function onPostExecute and modify your GUI from there.

Comment: i have tried to raise only a Toast from the asynk task but the activity was getting closed immediately so the toast was not raised.

Answer (score 0):

out of memory, catch LOG onDestoy() method

Answer (score 0):

Have you mentioned your receiver in the `android manifest` file,
Add this bunch of code in your `manifest file`,

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">

            <action />

        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```